# Flutter: Is there an onhold option instead of oppressed once to repeat SetState

Tags: button, flutter, counter, setstate, flutter-onpressed

I want a button which I can hold down and then Setstate is repeating, unless I stop holding it.

I am a beginner and working at my first app. I want to calculate volume. People have to put in height, width and dept. I don't want in text(form)field, because the keyboard is necessary. I found a solution with two buttons, an add and a minus button.

I have it working, but people have to push the button very often to set the value of height they want.

I thought instead of oppressed, I use something as on hold and the counter is adding quickly. But I don't know the solution.

```
RawMaterialButton(
child: Icon(MdiIcons.minus),
onPressed: () {
setState(() {
width--;
```

Comment: Try the `Gesture Detector` it has an `onLongPress` that could start your "infinite loop of setState" and an `onLongPressEnd` to end it.

Comment: Hi Abbas, Thank you so much for helping me. I have tried your solution, but the loop does not working.

I have made an void:
    void _minusWidth() {
      setState(() {
        width--;
       print(width);
    });
  }

and then I used this in the code:

    GestureDetector(
                                onLongPress: _minusWidth,

I don't understand how to get the infinity en how I stop it with onLongPressEnd. I have search the documentation on Flutter, but I can not find it. Hope you can help me again!

Comment: Try putting it in a `while loop` and have a `boolean flag` that would be set to true (while holding) which would start the loop and false when you release which would stop it. I'm not sure it would work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I didn't fix it. It was to complex for me as a beginner.
I found another solution.
I made a row, with three children:
a minus button and a plus button for fine tuning
a slider-bar for the big steps.

This is the code I used, do you have better solutions, let me know. I just place it for other beginners like me.
I want to thank special @Abbas.M who tried to help me.

```
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    AnimatedOpacity(
                      opacity: height == 1 ? 0.0 : 1.0,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      child: RawMaterialButton(
                        child: Icon(MdiIcons.minus),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            height > 1 ? height-- : height = height;
                          });
                        },
                        constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
                          width: 25.0,
                          height: 25.0,
                        ),
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                        fillColor: white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SliderTheme(
                      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                        inactiveTrackColor: cAppBottomBar,
                        activeTrackColor: white,
                        thumbColor: white,
                        overlayColor: cShadow,
                        thumbShape:
                            RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 10.0),
                        overlayShape:
                            RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 17.0),
                      ),
                      child: Slider(
                          value: height.toDouble(),
                          min: 1,
                          max: 300,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              height = value.toInt();
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                    AnimatedOpacity(
                      opacity: height == 300 ? 0.0 : 1.0,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      child: RawMaterialButton(
                        child: Icon(Icons.add),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            height < 300 ? height++ : height = height;
                          });
                        },
                        constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(
                          width: 25.0,
                          height: 25.0,
                        ),
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                        fillColor: white,
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 4):

If this topic is still interesting for you, you could try `holding_gesture`, see https://pub.dev/packages/holding_gesture

Answer (score 0):

You should use GestureDetector widget's `onTapDown` (for holding the button) and `onTapUp` (for the release user's finger) features.

```
GestureDetector(
                onTapDown: (details) {
                  print("Someone is touchin' me !!");
                },
                onTapUp: (details) {
                  print("I relaxed, oh.");
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.brown,
                )),
```